# How to add alternate row color in html table?

Tags: html, vb.net

I have a function converting datatable into html table in vb.net, but i want to add alternate row color in each row. I added a css on the code but it didn't work. How will I make this happen?

Below is my code:

```
 Public Function ConvertToHtml(ByVal targetTable As DataTable) As String

 Dim myHtmlFile As String = ""

    'Get a worker object.
    Dim strBuilder As New StringBuilder()

    'Open tags and write the top portion.
    strBuilder.Append("<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>")
    strBuilder.Append("<head>")
    strBuilder.Append("<title>")
    strBuilder.Append("Page-")
    strBuilder.Append(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
    strBuilder.Append("</title>")

    strBuilder.Append("<style type='text/css'>")
    strBuilder.Append(".tr:nth-child(even){")
    strBuilder.Append("background-color: #dae5f4}")
    strBuilder.Append("</style>")

    strBuilder.Append("</head>")
    strBuilder.Append("<body>")
    strBuilder.Append("<table border='1px' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' ")
    strBuilder.Append("style='border: solid 1px Silver; font-family:Franklin Gothic Book; font-size: 14px;'>") 'font-size: x-small

    'Add the headings row.

    strBuilder.Append("<tr align='left' valign='top' bgcolor='#006699'>") '("<tr align='left' valign='top'>")

    For Each myColumn As DataColumn In targetTable.Columns
        strBuilder.Append("<td align='center' valign='top' style='color:#ffffff'>")
        strBuilder.Append(myColumn.ColumnName)
        strBuilder.Append("</td>")
    Next

    strBuilder.Append("</tr>")

    'Add the data rows.
    For Each myRow As DataRow In targetTable.Rows
        strBuilder.Append("<tr align='left' valign='top'>")

        For Each myColumn As DataColumn In targetTable.Columns
            strBuilder.Append("<td align='left' valign='top' style='font-size:12px'>")
            strBuilder.Append(myRow(myColumn.ColumnName).ToString())
            strBuilder.Append("</td>")
        Next

        strBuilder.Append("</tr>")
    Next

    'Close tags.
    strBuilder.Append("</table>")
    strBuilder.Append("</body>")
    strBuilder.Append("</html>")

    'Get the string for return.
    myHtmlFile = strBuilder.ToString()
    Return myHtmlFile
End Function
```

*********UPDATE******

Here's the program's output as suggested

[image]

Comment: Seeing you are all blue - can you post the HTML output for the <style> section and a sample <tr> row?   You didn't mention browser version, but it is also worth mentioning that nth-child is not supported by older IE versions (e.g. ie8 and before).

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS has a small syntax error causing your problem.  You really want to have:

```
strBuilder.Append("<style type='text/css'>")
strBuilder.Append("tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #dae5f4}")
strBuilder.Append("</style>")
```

Notice I removed the "." from in front of tr -- which makes it the element "tr" instead of items have the CSS class of "tr".

I would also remove the inline background in your tr - changing it to:

```
strBuilder.Append("<tr align='left' valign='top'>")
```

And move the bgcolor to your CSS, leaving you finally with:

```
strBuilder.Append("<style type='text/css'>")
strBuilder.Append("tr{background-color: #006699;}")
strBuilder.Append("tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #dae5f4}")
strBuilder.Append("</style>")
```

I've included an example HTML output, showing the functional CSS.

```html
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
    <head>
    <title>
    Page-
    strBuilder.Append(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
    </title>

    <style type='text/css'>
    tr{background-color: #006699}
    tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #dae5f4}
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
    <table border='1px' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='border: solid 1px Silver; font-family:Franklin Gothic Book; font-size: 14px;'>
    <tr align='left' valign='top' style='background-color:black'>
        <td align='center' valign='top' style='color:#ffffff'>
            Sample
        </td>
        <td align='center' valign='top' style='color:#ffffff'>
            Sample
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr align='left' valign='top'>
            <td align='left' valign='top' style='font-size:12px'>
                Sample
            </td>
            <td align='left' valign='top' style='font-size:12px'>
                Sample
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr align='left' valign='top'>
            <td align='left' valign='top' style='font-size:12px'>
                Sample
            </td>
            <td align='left' valign='top' style='font-size:12px'>
                Sample
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr align='left' valign='top'>
            <td align='left' valign='top' style='font-size:12px'>
                Sample
            </td>
            <td align='left' valign='top' style='font-size:12px'>
                Sample
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I went ahead and included an HTML snippet based on your program's output where you can see the alternating rows functional - can you post your program's output?